# creating list of custom object in mvc2 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Model::::

```
 public class Model1

    {

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string ProductName { get; set; }

    }
```

ViewModel::::

```
public class ViewModel1

    {

      public  List<Model1> model1;

    }
```

controller:::::::::

```
var sent = entities.Table1.Where<Table1>(o => o.SenderUserId == userId );

          ViewModel1 newViewModel = new ViewModel1();

            foreach (Table1 gf in sent)

            {

                var nmodel = new Model1();

                nmodel.Name = gf.Name;

                nmodel.ProductName = doSomething(gf.ProductName);

               // **Here I'm stuck====how do I add nmodel to newViewModel**

               //**newViewModel.Add===does not work**

            }

          return View(newViewModel);
```

Comment: Are you getting a null reference exception?  Can you be more clear about "does not work"?

Comment: I do not get 'Add' as the viewModel does not have an add method.

Answer (score 1):

A quick guess based on the code you posted, is that you never instantiated the collection.

```
public class ViewModel1
{
    List<Model1> model1;
    public ViewModel1()
    {
        model1=new List<Model1>();
    }
}
......
newViewModel.model1.Add(nmodel);
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed the code, its actually
 public List<Model1> model1;

Comment: Yes, I see that it's public, You still need to instantiate it somewhere before you can call Add.  I added the correct syntax to add to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have a feeling this will work, just another thing:
var sent = entities.Table1.Where<Table1>(o => o.SenderUserId == userId )
will sometimes give me null values.

Comment: y, I know, should i ask it in a diff question, thisis the first time I'm using stackoverflow

Comment: Yes that makes the most sense to me in this instance.  However, if it SHOULD ALWAYS return something, then a better practice might be to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Change your ViewModel as follows
ViewModel::::

```
public class ViewModel1
{
    public  List<Model1> model1 = new List<Model1>();
}
```

Change your controller as follows:

```
var sent = entities.Table1.Where<Table1>(o => o.SenderUserId == userId );
ViewModel1 newViewModel = new ViewModel1();
foreach (Table1 gf in sent)
{
        var nmodel = new Model1();
        nmodel.Name = gf.Name;
        nmodel.ProductName = doSomething(gf.ProductName);
        newViewModel.model1.Add(nmodel);
}

return View(newViewModel);
```

Comment: y, that is what brook said, though ur answer will be more clear to new people, just add '()'in the viewmodel, thanks for your reply